# My App Auto Shuts Down When I Add the Advert Implementation to the Build.Gradle

Tags: android, admob, android-7.0-nougat

My app works. Then I add the one line into my `build.gradle` (ie the admob adverts):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
```

and then my app will not work, automatically closing as soon as it loads.

My phone is Android Nougat 7.0 (ie sdk 24.0). As far as I am aware the ads should be ok on that. Am I correct?

Any idea why this fails?

Edit:

The error is (sorry it does not format very well, please scroll right):

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.myapp.www.myapp, PID: 6415
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    ******************************************************************************
                                                                                                    * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
                                                                                                    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
                                                                                                    * to find your app ID.                                                       *
                                                                                                    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
                                                                                                    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
                                                                                                    ******************************************************************************
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5977)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5545)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5484)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    ******************************************************************************
                                                                                                    * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
                                                                                                    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
                                                                                                    * to find your app ID.                                                       *
                                                                                                    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
                                                                                                    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
                                                                                                    ******************************************************************************
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzek.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.5.0:15)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.5.0:1)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5974)
                                                                                                        ... 10 more
```

My project `build.gradle` is (note I have to hash out `allprojects` or otherwise the gradle will not sync):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
}

//allprojects {
//    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
//    }
//}
```

My android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp.www.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <!--        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"-->
    <!--        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"-->
    <!--        tools:targetApi="33"-->
    <!--        tools:ignore="ExtraText">-->


<!--    <meta-data-->
<!--        android:name="android.app.lib_name"-->
<!--        android:value="" />-->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round_foreground"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My app `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.www.myapp"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1021
        versionName "1.021"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        javaCompileOptions {
            gradle.projectsEvaluated {
                tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
                    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def billing_version = "6.0.1"
    /* This is for the billing library we are using */
    /* implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44' */
    /* New Google's Billing */
    /* implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.0' */
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"

    /* TEMP ADVERTS */
    /* This is for adverts */
    /* implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0' */
    /* Consent for Adverts GDPR */
    /* /* implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6' */
    /* implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7' */

    /* Adverts */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
    /* GDPR */
    /* implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.1.0' */

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    /* This for ImmutableList */
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

In my `onCreate` function:

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have to add error log.  No one can answer this way!

Comment: Hi Faruk. I have updated with everything I hope is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error log:

```
******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************
```

You should provide a valid id for it to start. Find your app ID from Ad Manager web interface. Moreover you can use a sample ID to test the SDK. If you try with this ID, the application will open.

You must replace this part with your own id.

```
android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"
```

With sample ID:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Faruk. That did the trick. (PS. Sorry for taking so long to get back to you to tell you if it worked. I have not had access to my programming PC for a couple of days.)

Comment: oh! no problem.